# Problemas con un Script de TradingView (python)

Tags: python, script, pine-script

Ayer intente hacer un script para marcar los cruces de las EMAs en TradingView partiendo de un script de codigo abierto. Me muestra las EMAs pero no puedo marcar los cruces entre ellas. Adjunto el codigo:

```
study(title="5EMAs Ger Mod [by Prinick]", shorttitle="5EMAs2", overlay=true)

EMA8 = input(8, minval=1, title="EMA8"),
EMA21 = input(21, minval=1, title="EMA21")
EMA55 = input(55, minval=1, title="EMA55"),
EMA233 = input(233, minval=1, title="EMA233"),
EMA377 = input(377, minval=1, title="EMA377"),

plot(ema(close, EMA8), color=white, linewidth=2)
plot(ema(close, EMA21), color=red, linewidth=2)
plot(ema(close, EMA55), color=blue, linewidth=2)
plot(ema(close, EMA233), color=purple, linewidth=2)
plot(ema(close, EMA377), color=green, linewidth=2)
plot(cross(EMA8, EMA21) ? EMA21 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(EMA21, EMA55) ? EMA21 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(EMA55, EMA233) ? EMA21 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(EMA233, EMA377) ? EMA21 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(EMA8, EMA21) ? EMA21 : na, color = (EMA21 - EMA8 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 3)
plot(cross(EMA21, EMA55) ? EMA55 : na, color = (EMA55 - EMA21 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 3)
plot(cross(EMA55, EMA233) ? EMA233 : na, color = (EMA233 - EMA55 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 3)
plot(cross(EMA233, EMA377) ? EMA377 : na, color = (EMA377 - EMA233 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 3)
```

Me grafica perfectamente las EMAs pero no me grafica los puntos de los cruces. La parte extraida de otro codigo abierto seria la ultima. muestro parte del codigo original.

```
plot(wt1, color=green)
plot(wt2, color=red)
plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 3)
plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = (wt2 - wt1 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 2)
```

Segun la sintaxis de los comandos esta correcto. Si a alguien se le ocurre alguna idea de que puede llegar a ser mi problema, todo comentario es bienvenido.
Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Sé que es una pregunta vieja, pero recién hoy me uno a esta comunidad. Quizás la respuesta le sirva a alguien mas

Primero, te recomiendo trabajar en *//@version=4*, y este script es *//@version=2*

El problema es que estas cruzando los **input**. No estas cruzando las lineas de EMAS

Tenes que:

- Calcular las EMAs
- Trazar las EMAs
- Calcular los cruces y trazarlos

```
//@version=4
study(title="5EMAs Ger Mod [by Prinick]", shorttitle="5EMAs2", overlay=true)
i_EMA8 = input(8, minval=1, title="i_EMA8")
i_EMA21 = input(21, minval=1, title="i_EMA21")
i_EMA55 = input(55, minval=1, title="i_EMA55")
i_EMA233 = input(233, minval=1, title="i_EMA233")
i_EMA377 = input(377, minval=1, title="i_EMA377")

EMA8 = ema(close, i_EMA8)
EMA21 = ema(close, i_EMA21)
EMA55 = ema(close, i_EMA55)
EMA233 = ema(close, i_EMA233)
EMA377 = ema(close, i_EMA377)

plot(EMA8, color=color.white, linewidth=2)
plot(EMA21, color=color.red, linewidth=2)
plot(EMA55, color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(EMA233, color=color.purple, linewidth=2)
plot(EMA377, color=color.green, linewidth=2)

plot(cross(EMA8, EMA21)? EMA21 : na, color=color.black, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=4)
plot(cross(EMA21, EMA55) ? EMA21 : na, color=color.black, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=4)
plot(cross(EMA55, EMA233) ? EMA21 : na, color=color.black, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=4)
plot(cross(EMA233, EMA377) ? EMA21 : na, color=color.black, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=4)
plot(cross(EMA8, EMA21) ? EMA21 : na, color=EMA21 - EMA8 > 0 ? color.red : color.lime, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3)
plot(cross(EMA21, EMA55) ? EMA55 : na, color=EMA55 - EMA21 > 0 ? color.red : color.lime, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3)
plot(cross(EMA55, EMA233) ? EMA233 : na, color=EMA233 - EMA55 > 0 ? color.red : color.lime, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3)
plot(cross(EMA233, EMA377) ? EMA377 : na, color=EMA377 - EMA233 > 0 ? color.red : color.lime, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3)
```